# Collision / distance to volumes from point in OpenGL ES on Android

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, collision-detection, mesh

[is user inside volume OpenGL ES Java Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8adsb.png)
I have an opengl renderer that shows airspaces.

I need to calculate if my location already converted in float[3] is inside many volumes.

I also want to calculate the distance with the nearest volume.

Volumes are random shapes extruded along z axis.

What is the most efficient algorithm to do that?

I don t want to use external library.

Comment: Are you able to use space partioning algorithms in your app? Do the volumes change dynamically or their properties are pre-defined?

Comment: I do everything myself in pure java. My meshes are converted from a tex file to triangle_strips. I calculated the center of points for approximate distance. I can add min-max X,Y,Z also. The meshes are final. they will not change.

Comment: See the answer.

Comment: This might be better asked on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have here is a [Nearest Neighbor Search problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). Since your meshes are constant and won't change, you should probably use a space partioning algorithm. It's a big topic but, in short, you generally need to use a tree structure and sort all the objects to be put into various tree nodes. You'll need to pre-calculate the tree itself. There are plenty of books and tutorials on the net about space partioning, and you could also at source code of, for example, id Software products like Doom, Quake etc. to see how this algorithms (BSP, at least) are used. The efficiency of each algorithm depends on what you have and what you need. Using BSP trees, for example, you'll have the objects sorted from nearest to farthest so you can quickly get the one you need.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have links to code exemple ready to use that apply to OpenGL ES in Java? I don't find it on GitHub. I added an image to represent my problem. Here is a link to my project page on facebook: https://www.facebook.com/FlyOverlay/

Comment: @gregouplus I don't have a link, sorry. Actualy they aren't something specific to OpenGL ES, they (or some of them) would more or less sort a list of objects in order from nearest to farthest. In case you probably could just walk a tree-structure recursively to find the nearest volume.

Comment: In fact my problem is half solved. I know how to calculate if i am inside the bounding box of my volume. what i need is two things: \n calculate if i am inside a 2d plane shape with my lat/lon. \n for the ground to calculate where is my vertical cutting a square of different altitudes floating points. I know the x/y/z of the points. but where am cutting that plane. It's a simple maths geometry problem i think.